# (Android) How to change the name of the images already stored in gallery programatically

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am making an application where i have to upload the pictures that are already stored in the gallery on the AWS Servers.The problem is that i have to name those pictures according to the timestamp ,i.e. the time at which they are being uploaded.Below is the code that am using to get the images from gallery.
Beginupload is the method that am using to upload the images in the AWS bucket.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_Gallery: {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_Gallery
                        && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)

                {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();

                        try {
                            String path = getPath(uri);
                           // String p=path.replace(path, timeStamp+".jpg");
                            beginUpload(path);

                        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(this,
                                    "Unable to get the file from the given URI.  See error log for details",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to upload file from the given uri", e);
                        }
```

Comment: Can't you use the timestamp on the image that is stored in the EXIF data of that image

Comment: No...i need to change the name to the time at which the photo will be uploaded to the AWS.

Comment: Would anyone even reply?

Comment: Try creating an duplicate image you want and rename it and then upload that image